# Get only Right values from Either sequence

Tags: scala

This code prints `List(1, 2, ())`

```
    def f1(i:Int): Either[String,Int] = if (i > 0) Right(1) else Left("error 1") 
    def f2(i:Int): Either[String,Int] = if (i > 0) Right(2) else Left("error 2") 
    def f3(i:Int): Either[String,Int] = if (i > 0) Right(3) else Left("error 3") 

    val seq = Seq(f1(1),f2(1),f3(-1))

    val x = seq.map { f => if (f.isRight) f.right.get }
    println(x)
```

I need an array filtered by `isRight` is true, eliminating any other values. In the example above, the result I would need is `List(1, 2)`. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remember that in Scala, `if` is an expression that returns a value. In your case, the value is either `f.right.get` (if `Right` is present in `Either`), or `Unit` otherwise. To filter only on `Right` values, use `filter`:

```
val x = seq.filter(_.isRight).map(_.right.get)
```

Comment: Not sure why this was accepted when it's a known aspect of Scala practices to avoid dangling .get calls. The answer below is a better solution. Downvoting because IMHO I would encourage the community to follow best practices. Rightly stated by  Mateusz Kubuszok in the comment section of the answer below.

Answer (score 27):

Use `collect` and pattern match to select the case you are interested in.

```
seq.collect { case Right(value) => value}
```

Lets try on

## Scala REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    def f1(i:Int): Either[String,Int] = if (i > 0) Right(1) else Left("error 1")
    def f2(i:Int): Either[String,Int] = if (i > 0) Right(2) else Left("error 2")
    def f3(i:Int): Either[String,Int] = if (i > 0) Right(3) else Left("error 3")

    val seq = Seq(f1(1),f2(1),f3(-1))


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

f1: (i: Int)Either[String,Int]
f2: (i: Int)Either[String,Int]
f3: (i: Int)Either[String,Int]
seq: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left(error 3))

scala> seq.collect { case Right(value) => value }
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

#### Functional programming is about expressions and not statements

In

```
val x = seq.map { f => if (f.isRight) f.right.get }
```

The below returns `Unit` in case f is not right. So, you get `Unit` as third value.

```
if (f.isRight) f.right.get
```

Functional way is to use have else part also. But In this case, there is no meaningful else case.

Comment: your answer is also correct, but I can only choose one

Comment: This answer not only correct but also superior - IMHO using `get` is antipattern most of the time.

Comment: I like more the answer I selected that uses filter, the `get` will never fail as it's conditional to `isRight`

Answer (score 0):

Since Scala 2.13 [Either](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html) is right biased, so you can simply map to all `Right` values with a flatMap:

```scala
sequence.flatMap(_.toOption)
```

In case you need both values, you might also be interested in [partitionMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#partitionMap%5BA1,A2%5D(f:A=%3EEither%5BA1,A2%5D):(CC%5BA1%5D,CC%5BA2%5D)):

```scala
val values: Seq[Either[String, String]] = Seq(
  Right("Good value 1"),
  Left("Bad value 1"),
  Right("Good value 2"),
  Left("Bad value 2"),
  Left("Bad value 3"),
)

// pick both sides in one fell swoop
val (bad, good) = values.partitionMap(identity)

println(s"Good: ${good.mkString(", ")}")
println(s"Bad:  ${bad.mkString(", ")}")

/* prints
 Good: Good value 1, Good value 2
 Bad:  Bad value 1, Bad value 2, Bad value 3
*/
```

[Try it for yourself](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NbtMoy3CS1iHhKY86pUm6A)